# position to insert element in inserionsort (equality of probablity)

Tags: sorting

prove that in algorithm insertionsort, for successively considered element a[i] there is equal probablity that element will be inserted in one of i positions:

a[1] <= a[2] <= ... <= a[i-1]

To my eye it is obvious and I can't prove it. What is your opinion ?

Comment: This is just general advice, but when something is so obvious it seems to need no proof, proof by contradiction can be helpful. Start by wondering what would happen if the probabilities were *not* equal, and see if you can reach some absurdity by assuming that to be true.

Comment: I know that it would be contradiction with fact that permutation is random. Then a[i] is not random. But it is absurdity. Unfortunately, I can't show this contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

Try counting the number of permutations where it is inserted in position $i$.  How does this number depend on $i$?  That will lead immediately to a proof.

In general, when you need to calculate a probability of some event, and you have a uniform distribution, one way is to use counting to compute the probability: count the number of outcomes where the event is true, and then divide by the total number of possible outcomes.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you properly. There is only one permutation when a[i] will be inserted on postition i. And there is exactly one permutation when a[i] will be inserted on position 3....                                                       So we have exactly i permutations. The question is  why every of them (i permutations) has equal probablity ?